# Why the JDK's jps command does not list the process of JBoss instance?

Tags: java, linux, jboss, jvm

I am currently using JBoss at work to run some Java web application in Linux. The running instance of JBoss is listed with the process list command `ps aux |grep java`, and the relevant output is something like `jboss    19622  0.3 35.8 3410688 1391068 ?     Sl   Dec13   3:27 /opt/wsp/jdk1.8.0/bin/java -D[Standalone] -server -XX:+UseCompressedOops -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true`...

According to my understanding, there should be corresponding JVMs listed by using JDK's command `jps`. But when I typed `jps` in terminal, only one record is listed, something like `12073 jps`. I am pretty confused about why is it like that, anyone can explain? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is jBoss run by the same user that you used to run jps?

Comment: @AlexFilatov Thanks a lot :) You are actually right! I checked and found that JBoss was ran with sudo :) Thanks a lot and please write your answer here and I can confirm it right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that jBoss is run by a different user. `ps aux` shows every process of the system, while `jps` is restricted by permissions of the user running the command.